# Using spawnSync to invoke ImageMagick's `convert` with arguments

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I'm trying to use [`spawnSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawnsynccommand-args-options) to invoke ImageMagick's [`convert`](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) command with the necessary options. I can run the command fine directly:

```
$ ls testimage.*
testimage.png

$ convert testimage.png -define dds:mipmaps=99 -define dds:compression=dxt5 testimage.dds
$ ls testimage.*
testimage.dds  testimage.png
```

However, if I supply those arguments in an array to `spawnSync()`, I get an error:

```js
> const {spawnSync} = require('child_process')
undefined

> const args = ['testimage.png', '-define dds:mipmaps=99', '-define dds:compression=dxt5', 'testimage.dds']
undefined

> spawnSync('convert', args, {encoding:'utf-8'}).stderr
"convert-im6.q16: unrecognized option `-define dds:mipmaps=99' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1410.\n"
```

If I join all the arguments into a single argument, `convert` shows its usage, so it doesn't like that, either:

```js
> spawnSync('convert', [args.join(' ')], {encoding:'utf-8'}).stdout
'Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org\n' +
  'Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC\n' +
  'License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php\n' +
  'Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP \n' +
  'Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib\n' +
  'Usage: convert-im6.q16 [options ...] file [ [options ...] file ...] [options ...] file\n' +
...
```

How can I pass my sanitized arguments along in a way that will make it work as though I typed the command line shown above?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `-define` and `dds:mipmaps=99` are separate arguments. This works as desired:

```js
const {spawnSync} = require('child_process')
const args = [
   'testimage.png',
   '-define',
   'dds:mipmaps=99',
   '-define',
   'dds:compression=dxt5',
   'testimage.dds'
]
spawnSync('convert', args, {encoding:'utf-8'})
```